# Can a War Caster use Shocking Grasp as a reaction without having it as a Cantrip?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

When leveling up my character, I have the option to take the [War Caster](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/War+Caster) feat which says I can use a reaction to cast Shocking Grasp at a target moving out of melee range. However, my character does not have Shocking Grasp as a cantrip.

If I take the War Caster feat, will my character be able to use Shocking Grasp as a reaction even if they don't have it as a Cantrip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, they can/will.**

I've had the *War Caster* feat on both my main character sorcerer and on Shadowheart, and the prompt will show up under the right conditions without either of them having the *Shocking Grasp* cantrip.